# SharpDX ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile to PixelShader

Tags: sharpdx

Currently i am working on a migration from SlimDX to SharpDX. Some things are different between them, like loading shaders etc:

I have a problem creating the `PixelShader` class (same applies to the `VertexShader` class). The problem is, every example I found on this subject will not compile.

For example:

```
using (var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(filename, "PS", "ps_5_0", shaderFlags))
    shader.PixelShader = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);
```

The problem is, `SharpDX.Direct3D11.PixelShader` does not take a `ComplilationResult` as parameter. I could use the `vertexShaderByteCode.Bytecode` which is a `ShaderBytecode`, but this is also invalid.

There is a `vertexShaderByteCode.Bytecode.Data` which is a `DataStream`. I might create the `byte[]` from it, but I think this could be solved easier? Did I missed something?

*using: SharpDX 3.1.1*

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem:

Looks like i need to reference the `SharpDX.D3DCompiler` also, to compile for DX11. It was using the DX9 compiler.

`SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode`*(DX11)* **vs** `SharpDX.Direct3D9.ShaderBytecode`*(DX9)*

I'll leave this for anyone who has the same struggles.

Answer (score 0):

`CompilationResult` is returned by the compile and you can test if the bytecode is null, if it is, you can then check the error codes (Best in debug though :)).

```
HasErrors : boolean
Message : string
```

Check these also.